# WPF Datagrid OnPropertyChanged causes SelectionChanged event

Tags: wpf, datagrid, selectionchanged

I have a WPF Datagrid that is bound to a model.

Inside the model I have a property defined as

```
   public String status
    {
        get
        {
            return m_status;
        }
        set
        {
            m_status = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("status");           
        }
    }
```

This property informs the grid of changes via OnPropertyChanged.

I also handle the SelectionChanged event to trigger different activities.

```
 SelectionChanged="gridSongs_SelectionChanged"


    private void gridSongs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("gridSongs_SelectionChanged " + sender.ToString());
    }
```

During testing this I have noticed that every time I change the property "status" in code the grid updates automatically (which is what I want) but also fires the SelectionChanged Event as well.

Is there any way I can stop the event from firing when I change the model from code but let it go through when user clicks an item in the grid ?

Maybe I could use a different event for the manual selection of items in the grid ?

thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can stop the event from firing when I change the model from code but let it go through when user clicks an item in the grid?

No, but there is a simple workaround. Add a `private bool isLocal` variable and set it to `true` before you make any changes and back to `false` afterwards:

```
isLocal = true;
status = "Some Value";
isLocal = false;
```

Then, in your `SelectionChanged` handler, check this variable and only react if it is `false`:

```
private void gridSongs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!isLocal ) Console.WriteLine("gridSongs_SelectionChanged " + sender.ToString());
}
```

Comment: thanks Sheridan. That will work. I actually implemented another event "mouseup" and moved my logic I had in SelectionChanged event. That seems to work as well. I just needed some extra logic to check if a row is selected or not but I like your version as well. Will give that a try.